# Excel Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 The connection for viewing your linked Microsoft Excel worksheet was lost

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a VBscript that connects to a excel file and queries the data using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. I'm just displaying the recordcount right now but when I have the document open, the count is wrong. When the excel document is closed, it is correct. I'm getting an error now "The connection for viewing your linked Microsoft Excel worksheet was lost" CODE: 80004005 Source:Microsoft Access Database Engine. I've used VBScript to pull this data many times before but never got this error.

Any ideas on what is causing this?

The connection string is this:

```
cnnExcel.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & strExcelFilePath & ";" & "Extended Properties=" &  Chr(34) & "Excel 12.0 Xml;Readonly=1;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1" & Chr(34) & ";"
```

Recordset is this:

```
rsExcel.open "SELECT * FROM [col$] WHERE [name] <>''", cnnExcel, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: Nope, no ideas. If you [show your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) though, we can help and hopefully generate some!

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. *The connection was lost* means that...well... the connection was lost. When your web browser can't refresh a page because your ISP goes down or the site goes off-line, it tells you it can't load the page because it can't connect, which means *the connection was lost*. In this case, Excel can't refresh the data because it can't connect with the source of the data because *the connection was lost*. When you open the workbook, Excel tries to refresh the data and can't. I'm not sure how that is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this when it happened to me. My SQL was failing because source data had a record ID of 10054748 in a cell which was formatted as a date causing an overflow error which caused another non-erroring column to return a NULL, even though the error was not in one of the columns queried. The field's data was type text in any case, and the errant formatting caused by pasting a copied recordset from Toad and XL TextToColumns automatically parsing it based on a different data set parsed earlier in the day! The solution was changing that column's formatting back to General which eliminated the overflow errors. Summary: probably any errors in source data to be selected using SQL and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 can cause null values to be returned and unexpected failure of a where clause that references those null values, source data should be clean, formatting should be minimized and well understood!